# Show that f is multiplicative and evaluate f at prime powers

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I'm trying to prove the problem about multiplicative function.

The problem is the following :

Let $f(n) = $ #{($n_1, n_2$) $\in$ $\mathbb{N^2}$ : $lcm$($n_1, n_2) = n$}. Now, prove that $f$ is multiplicative and evaluate $f$ at prime powers.

I don't know where I start with. Does anyone give me the idea for this? The only thing that I found is, it can be a multiplicative function regardless of the choice of $n_1$ and $n_2$, i.e, even if $n_1$ and $n_2$ are not co-primes, it can be the multiplicative function.

Comment: The way I start would be to find the value of $f(1)$ first, then $f(2)$, then $f(3)$ and see whether that’s equal to $f(2)$. Then I’d look at $f(6)$ and see whether the direct, hands-on, pencil computation was giving me any insight. (Do not “help” yourself by using machine computation.)

Comment: I already tried to make an example to see the exact value of $f(n)$. In my calculation, $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 3, f(3) = 3, f(4) = 5, ...f(6) = 9$ And, definitely, regardless of ($n_1, n_2$) = 1 or d, it can be the multiplicative function.

Comment: Then can you see how to take the $N_p=f(p)$ pairs and the $N_q=f(q)$ pairs, where $p$ and $q$ are different primes, and see how taking one pair of each kind gives you a pair of inters with lcm equal to $pq$?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplicative: let $m$ and $n$ be relatively prime. If $m_1, m_2, n_1, n_2 \in \Bbb N$ and $\text{lcm}(m_1, m_2) = m$, $\text{lcm}(n_1, n_2)=n$, then $\text{lcm}(m_1n_1, m_2n_2)=mn$ (prove this!). Also, given $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb N$ with $\text{lcm}(x_1,x_2)=mn$, let $m_1$ be the factor of $x_1$ that contains all the prime factos of $m$, $n_1$ the factor of $x_1$ that contains all the prime factors of $n$, and similarly $m_2, n_2$. Use this to show there is a bijective correspondence between the quadruples $(m_1, m_2), (n_1,n_2)$ that define $f(m)$ and $f(n)$ on the one hand, and the pairs $(x_1, x_2)$ that define $f(mn)$ on the other hand.

$f(p^k)$ - Both $n_1$ and $n_2$ must be powers of $p$, and the greatest exponent must be $k$. A direct count shows that $f(p^k)=2k+1$.

Comment: I agree with $f(p^k) = 2k+1$ :)

Comment: did you see that $f(n) = \sum_{d | n} g(n/d)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 - was that important? The solution doesn't need it and seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: It isn't straightforward to me, that's why I ask if you noted that $f(n) = \sum_{d | n} 2^{\omega(d)}$

Comment: @user1952009 - I believe I sketched a complete proof with only easy details left out, am I wrong? Were you able to follow what I said? Did you run into any difficulties filling in the details?

Comment: I just asked if you could see with your method that $f(n) = \sum_{d | n} 2^{\omega(d)}$ that's all (and I'm the one who upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

- The set of  couples $\qquad (a,b), \ \ lcm(a,b) = n$

  maps bijectively to the set of couples $\ (d,A),\ \ d | n,\ \  A | \frac{n}{d}, \ \ gcd(A,\frac{n}{d A})=1$

  $\qquad $(let $d = gcd(a,b), \ A = \frac{a}{d}, \ B = \frac{b}{d} = \frac{n}{Ad}$)

  so that :

  $$f(n) = \sum_{d | n} \sum_{A | \frac{n}{d}} 1_{gcd(A, \frac{n}{dA}) = 1} $$
- Assuming $$g(n) = \sum_{A | n} 1_{gcd(A, \frac{n}{A}) = 1}$$
  is multiplicative, we have that 
  $$f(n) = \sum_{d | n} g(n/d) = \sum_{d | n} g(d)$$
  is multiplicative too.
- Show that $n = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{e_i} \implies g(n) = 2^k$,
  i.e. $$g(n) = 2^{\omega(n)}$$
  where $\omega(n )$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

  So it is obvious that $$gcd(n,m) = 1 \quad \implies \quad \omega(nm) = \omega(n)+\omega(m) $$ $$ \implies \quad g(nm) = 2^{\omega(nm)} = 2^{\omega(n)+\omega(m)} = g(n)g(m) $$
- Since $g(1) = 1, g(p^k) = 2$, we have $$f(p^k) = \sum_{d | p^k} g(d) = \sum_{m=0}^k g(p^m) = 1+\sum_{m=1}^k 2 = 2k+1$$

Comment: I could not follow why $f(n) = $ #{($n_1, n_2$) $\in$ $\mathbb{N^2}$ : $lcm$($n_1, n_2) = n$} can be defined as a  $$f(n) = \sum_{d | n} \sum_{A | \frac{n}{d}} 1_{gcd(A, \frac{n}{dA}) = 1} $$, in your words. Could you explain it for me?

Comment: @D.Choi $n = lcm(a,b) = \frac{ab}{gcd(a,b)}$. let $d = gcd(a,b), A = \frac{a}{d}, B = \frac{b}{d}$ it becomes $gcd(A,B) = 1, n = lcm(dA,dB) = d A B, $, i.e. with $B = \frac{n}{dA}$ :  $$ d | n, A | \frac{n}{d}, gcd(A,\frac{n}{dA}) = 1$$
and those couples $(d,A)$ are clearly one-to-one with the original couples $(a,b)$

Comment: I could understand these materials about $lcm$, $gcd$ properties. But, my question is about relationship between your $f(n)$ which was re-defined with $gcd$ and the original $f(n)$. How could you deduce the re-defined $f(n)$?

Comment: @D.Choi "are clearly one-to-one" : instead of counting the number of couples $(a,b)$ with a certain property we count the couples $(d,A)$ with another property, and all we have to check is that the couples are one-to-one (try it you'll see it is easy)

Comment: Let's see it by example. Let a = 1, b = 2. Then, lcm (1 , 2) = 2 and gcd (1, 2) = 1. Thus, according to the definition of original $f(n)$, $f(2)$ = 3. And, did you mean that (1, 1) maps to (1, 2) bijectively?

Comment: Since f(2) = # {(1,2), (2,1), (2,2) } , i,e, f(2) = 3, did you mean that (1,2) maps to (1,1), (2,2) maps to (2,1), and (2,1) maps to (1,2) bijectively?

Comment: @D.Choi yes, $ d = gcd(a,b),A = \frac{a}{d}$ maps bijectively $(a,b), lcm(a,b) = n$  to $(d,A), d | n, gcd(A,\frac{n}{dA}) = 1$

Comment: @D.Choi everything is clear now ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still seeing your argument and trying to connect your argument with the new f(n).

Comment: @D.Choi  from  $(a,b)$ you can construct $(d,A)$, and from $(d,A)$ you can reconstruct $(a,b)$. Furthermore the property $lcm(a,b) = n$ implies that $d | n, gcd(A,\frac{n}{dA}) = 1$, and conversely $d | n, gcd(A,\frac{n}{dA}) = 1$ implies that $lcm(a,b)$. I.e. there is a bijection between the two sets. Finally the number of couples $(d,A)$ where $ d | n, gcd(A,\frac{n}{dA}) = 1$ is clearly given by the $f(n)$ I wrote

Comment: Yes, I agree with the steps when you deduce the $d|n$, $gcd (A, n/dA) = 1$. And, if I make a map given by (d, A) $\rightarrow$ (a,b), it will be bijective. But, what I still don't understand is this part "$$f(n) = \sum_{d | n} \sum_{A | \frac{n}{d}} 1_{gcd(A, \frac{n}{dA}) = 1} $$."

Comment: After this part, I could follow that re-defined $f(n)$ is multiplicative and evaluated power of prime number would be 2k + 1

Comment: $$\#\{(d,A) \ | \ \ \ d | n, A | \frac{n}{d}, gcd(A,\frac{n}{dA}) = 1 \} = \sum_{(d,A), d | n, A | \frac{n}{d}, gcd(A,\frac{n}{dA}) = 1} 1$$ $$ = \sum_{d | n} \ \ \sum_{A |  \frac{n}{d}, gcd(A,\frac{n}{dA}) = 1} 1 = \sum_{d | n} \sum_{A |  \frac{n}{d}} 1_{gcd(A,\frac{n}{dA}) = 1}$$ that's really the same with different notations @D.Choi